# Using Google's visualization organisation chart with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, charts, organization

I intend to implement an Organization Chart in my app and the best resource I found to display one was [Google's Organisational Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#Overview).

I'm using awesome_nested_set to maintain a tree structure in the database, and now I need to display the tree as an organization chart, for which I thought I could use the Google Org chart. Can it be done? If so, any tips or resources would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: +1 for pointing me at Gogle's Org Chart Api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I found this resource. Its called [GoogleVisualR](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/examples/interactive/org_chart).

It makes visualizing Google's org chart really easy, what's more, you write Ruby code and not a line in Javascript (Unless ofcourse you need to customize it). Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an Org Chart where i get User-profiles from a list connected to the with manager field.
I have used KineticJS to make a dynamic org chart and it is working fine for the moment, but i would like to know what others think about it